# LLVMIRGen: libjit.bc: error: Unknown attribute kind (61) (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM 8.0.1')

Tags: clang, llvm, jit, llvm-ir, glow

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
LLVM VERSION: 10.0.0
clang --version = 8.0.1

I get this error when I try to load the JIT library

LLVMIRGen: libjit.bc: error: Unknown attribute kind (61) (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM 8.0.1')
F0409 12:00:00.167050 23677 LLVMIRGen.cpp:216] Check failed: llmodule_.get() Unable to load the JIT library.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mismatched versions of LLVM and Clang. Maybe you need to uninstall one or the other?